# Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gradle

Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Ionic Framework: 3.9.2
Ionic App Scripts: 3.1.6
Angular Core: 5.0.3
Angular Compiler CLI: 5.0.3
Node: 8.9.1
OS Platform: macOS High Sierra
Navigator Platform: MacIntel
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)

cordova-android@6.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You can try

> cordova clean

And then run again

> cordova run android